# Table content alignment issues

Tags: tables

I still having table alignment issues. Have not been with LaTex for sometimes, but cannot figure out where is my problem.

I want to have below (using excel)

[image]

however, I get this in my MWE:

[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx, threeparttable}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]
\centering

\sisetup{table-format=2.2, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=2.0cm}
 \begin{tabular}{lSSS}
     \toprule
    %   \addlinespace[1.2ex]
     \multirow{2.4}{*}{\textbf{Study [Method]}} & Number of Stimulus Assessed & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Classification Temperature (\%)}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-3}
    &{\textbf{Dataset 1}}
     & {\textbf{Dataset 2}} \\
     \midrule
    Study 1 [Technology Method]  & 61.90 & 95.24 \\
    Study 2 [Analysis Method ] & 66.67 & 100.00 \\

\bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end {document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With employing of loaded packages (`makecell` and `tabularx`) in table code, its code become quite simpler and shorter. Also you need rethink, if you really need such long column headers: *Example Dataset*, can it be shorter *Example* (to me have the same meaning)?

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx, threeparttable}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for column headers
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \sisetup{table-format=3.2,
             table-column-width=6em}
    \renewcommand\cellalign{c}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
                    >{\raggedright}X
                    S[table-format=3.0]
                    SS
                             @{}}
     \toprule
\multirow{3.4}{=}{\thead{Study\\ {[Method]}}} 
    &   {\multirow{3.4}{*}{\thead{Number of\\ Stimulus\\ Assessed}}} 
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Classification Temperature (\%)}} \\
    \cmidrule{3-4}
    &       &   {\thead{Dataset 1\\(Example)}}
                    &   {\thead{Dataset 2\\(Example)}}  \\
     \midrule
Study 1 [Technology Method]  
    & 200   & 61.90 & 95.24     \\
Study 2 [Analysis Method ] 
    & 299   & 66.67 & 100.00    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end {document}
```

[image: image of table]

(red lines shows page layout)

Answer (score 4):

Your code gave me some errors but modifying it a bit I get this, if it helps:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx, threeparttable}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\def\arraystretch{1.5}



\begin{document}
    

    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        
        \sisetup{table-format=2.2, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=2.0cm}
    \adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{
        \begin{tabular}{llll}
            \toprule
            %   \addlinespace[1.2ex]
            \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\vtop{\hbox{\strut Study}\hbox{\strut [Method]}}}} & 
            \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\vtop{\hbox{\strut Number of}\hbox{\strut Stiumuli Assessed}}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Classification Temperature}} \\ \cline{3-4} 
            &                         & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \textbf{Dataset 1}}\hbox{\strut \textbf{[Example Dataset]}}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \textbf{Dataset 2}}\hbox{\strut \textbf{[Example Dataset]}}} \\ \hline
            {Study 1 {[}technology method{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{200} &                                 &                                 \\
            {Study 2 {[}analysis method{]}}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{200} &                                 &                                 \\
            
            \bottomrule
            
        \end{tabular}}
    \end{table}
    
\end {document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. Is it possible to make `Study [Method]` in 2 lines? like the want I want in excel?

Comment: Yes, i edited the answer.